# Create VisualSVN Server repository using command line

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

How do I create a new repository in VisualSVN server from commandline?

```
svnadmin create IKnowIShouldBeUsingMercurialOrGitRepository
```

...does nothing (allthough it does not fail).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run this command from path dedicated to VisualSVN repositories.